# Swift: How to close Safari if url is reached

Tags: ios, swift

How can I close Safari and return to the app once Safari loads a particular url? After running:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

In this case the user has to manually tap in the top let corner to return to the app. How can I force Safari to close once Safari reaches (for example) `http://example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

The only I would suggest is to use either `SFAuthenticationSession` or `SFSafariViewController` to handle your urls.